# How to code image link in react component

Tags: reactjs, laravel, components

In laravel blade I have this src:

```
data-src="data:image/;base64,{{ base64_encode(@file_get_contents($auction->thumbnail_link)) }}"
```

How to this the same in react component?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same but I think it better to use the [signed URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#signed-urls) from your private files

You can generate the URL in your controller then return it on the response.

Example:

```
URL::signedRoute('thumbnail', ['auction' => 1]);
```

Then add `signed` middleware to your route or check it on controller:

```
Route::get('/auctions/{auction}/thumbnail', function (Request $request) {
    // fetch and return the file
})->name('thumbnail')->middleware('signed');
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I want to use this in react component

Comment: @Mariusz You can use the private URL instead of the file base64 and it's a better solution for large files because the download problem,

Comment: @Mariusz If you want it as base64 also you need the method to return the file and in the front-end, you have to download and convert it to base64.